# Vlookup and Hlookup combination

Tags: excel, formula, vlookup

Im trying to return a value from a column but offset by one down,

```
77777   john smith      10:00   15:30

                        16:30   19:00
```

in this case the 16:30 value is what im trying to return

I was trying a combination of VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP, or an offset, but no luck

here is what i have

```
=VLOOKUP($F12,'IEX Daily Start-Stop Schds'!$A$1:$D$507,INDEX('IEX Daily Start-Stop Schds'!$A$1:$D$513,1,3),FALSE)
```

Comment: Some combination of INDEX and MATCH is probably what you want, but it's difficult to say without seeing a larger set of sample data.

Comment: I am trying this but cant get it to work `=OFFSET(LOOKUP(A315,A302:A331),1,2,1,1)`

Comment: What do you have in F12?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want

```
=index($D$1:$D$507,match($F12,$A$1:$A$507,0)+1)
```